# Reverse geocoding in xcode

Tags: xcode, mkreversegeocoder

I am making an app that takes your current location and determines the tax of the state you're in. So, I need to use reverse geocoding. I have found a few tutorials and similar questions on this site, but I haven't found anything that pertains to xcode, isn't outdated, and shows me what I need to do (more than an api). If anyone can help me, even by just giving me a link to a good tutorial, it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MKReverseGeocoder is deprecated as of iOS 5.0, so you have to use the class CLGeoCoder and a method called reverseGeocodeLocation.

Luckily for you, Apple has even an example on how to achieve what you are looking for.

Look out for "Geocoding a location using CLGeocoder" in the link below:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting some compile-time errors saying undefined symbols for architecture i386. Did I forget to import something?

Comment: I am using the newest one, 4.4

Comment: @SamJohnson And have you remembered to add the CoreLocation framework?

Comment: ok, i didn't see your edit. but now i am getting errors saying use of undeclared identifier

Comment: @SamJohnson Have you also remembered to import CoreLocation in your .h file like this?: #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

Comment: Maybe try to fix the errors yourself first and then get back to me if you cant. CLGeocoder is definitely the way to go though.

Comment: all right after exploring for awhile in the library i found what i was looking for. thanks for your time!